# Use Ito's lemma to find the process's mean and variance

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

The process is defined as
$$x_t = \exp{(kt+\sigma W_t)}$$
where $k,\sigma\in\mathbb{R}$ and $W_t$ is Brownian motion.

I want to find $Ex_t, Dx_t$.

To find $Ex_t$, I try to solve the equation:
\begin{align*}
&dx_t=k\exp{(kt+\sigma W_t)}dt+\sigma\exp{(kt+\sigma W_t)}dW_t+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\exp{(kt+\sigma W_t)}dt=\newline
&=kx_tdt+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\exp{(kt+\sigma W_t)}dt+\sigma\exp{(kt+\sigma W_t)}dt=\newline
&=x_tdt(k+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)+\sigma x_tdW_t
\end{align*}
and can't seem to arrive at the final solution from here.

Speaking of variance, I could use
\begin{align*}
&Dx_t = Ex^2_t-(Ex_t)^2\newline
&d(x_t^2)=2dx_t
\end{align*}
but to do so, I need that $Ex_t$.

Any advice on finding these moments could be helpful. Am I missing something?

Comment: @RolandF I don't understand why this equality holds.

Comment: I do not understand it either. Use the following easy to show fact:
$$
E[e^{\alpha W_t-\alpha^2t/2}]=1
$$
to find $E[x_t]$ and $E[x_t^2]\,.$ You just have to figure out what $\alpha$ is in each case.

Comment: @KurtG. I haven't managed to show that this fact holds and I can't use it to solve for $\alpha$ because $k,\sigma$ aren't explicitly tied in any way.

Comment: Hint: show that for a Gaussian $Z$ with mean zero
$$
E[e^{Z-{\rm Var}(Z)/2}]=1\,.
$$
Use the standard normal PDF and merge the two exponentials. Alternatively (since you mentioned it in the title) use Ito's lemma on $e^{\alpha W_t-\alpha t^2/2}\,.$

Comment: @KurtG. I get $$\frac{dy_t}{y_t}=(-2\alpha+\frac{1}{2}\alpha^2)dt+\alpha dW_t$$ where $y_t$ is the exponent. It's quite similar to the equation I have already got in the original post. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Yes. Wrong. The Ito formula should give $$\frac{dy_t}{y_t}=(-\frac12\alpha^2+\frac12\alpha^2)\,dt+\alpha\, dW_t=\alpha\,dW_t\,$$ where $y_t=e^{\alpha W_t-\alpha^2t/2}\,.$ This is usually called *exponential* not "expontent".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use that for a Gaussian $Z$ with mean zero and variance $v$
$$
E\big[e^{Z-v/2}\big]=1\,.
$$
Proof.

> $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{\sqrt{v}\,x-v/2}e^\frac{-x^2}{2}\,dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-\frac{(x-\sqrt{v})^2}{2}}\,dx=1\,.$$

This yields
$$
\boxed{\quad\phantom{\Bigg|}E\big[e^{\alpha W_t-\alpha^2t/2}\big]=1\,.\quad}
$$
which could also be shown using Ito's formula:

> $$M_t:=e^{\alpha W_t-\alpha^2t/2}\;\Longrightarrow\; dM_t=\alpha M_t\,dW_t\;\Longrightarrow\; M_t=1+\textstyle\int_0^t\alpha M_s\,dW_s\,.$$ The integral in the last term has expectation zero.

Then
\begin{align}
E\big[e^{k\,t\,+\,\sigma\, W_t}\big]&=e^{\,k\,t\,+\,\sigma^2\,t/2}\,,\\[2mm]
E\big[e^{2\,k\,t\,+\,2\,\sigma\, W_t}\big]&=e^{\,2\,k\,t\,+\,2\,\sigma^2\,t}
\end{align}
so that the variance of $e^{k\,t\,+\,\sigma\, W_t}$ is
\begin{align}
{\rm Var}\big[e^{k\,t\,+\,\sigma\, W_t}\big]&=e^{\,2\,k\,t\,+\,2\,\sigma^2\,t}\,-\,
e^{\,2\,k\,t\,+\,\sigma^2\,t}\\
&=e^{\,2\,k\,t\,+\,\sigma^2\,t}\,(e^{\sigma^2t}-1)\,.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

The exponential of a sum is the product, always

$$  \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{1}{n!} (k t + \sigma W_t)^n = \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{1}{n!}\sum _{m=0}^n \frac{n!}{m! (n-m)!}\  (k t )^m  \ \left(\sigma  W_t\right)^{n-m}  =   \ \sum _{l=0}^\infty \frac{1}{l!}\ (k t )^l \ \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{1}{n!} \left(\sigma  W_t\right)^n  = e^{k \ t} e^{\sigma W_t} $$

Since $W_t$ is normal distributed with $E(W_t^{2n+1})=0$, all one needs are the expectations of the even powers

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi } \sigma } \ \int_{-\infty }^{\infty } x^{2 n} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2 \sigma ^2}} \, dx  = \frac{2^n \sigma ^{2 n} \Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }}$$

Sum the even terms of the exponential series

$$ e^{k \ t} \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{t^n \left(2^n \sigma ^{2 n} \Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{\pi } (2 n)!} = e^{k t + \frac{\sigma ^2 t}{2}}$$